# Batch geocoding in R

Tags: r, geocoding, batch

I need to find a package in R or source code in R that performs batch geocoding using Bing, Yahoo, OpenStreetMap. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at this, http://www.r-bloggers.com/batch-geocoding-with-r-and-google-maps/? Google only but a place to start?

Comment: Not sure if this helps at all, but you might still take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068941/obtain-latitude-and-longitude-from-address-without-the-use-of-google-api)

Answer (score 19):

API conditions constantly change, but this should work right now.

<kbd>**OSM**</kbd>:

```r
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/nominatim")
library(nominatim)
b1 <- osm_geocode("Berlin, Germany")
b1[c("lat", "lon")]
```

<kbd>**Yahoo**</kbd>:

```r
devtools::install_github("trestletech/rydn")
library(rydn)
options(RYDN_KEY="yourAPIkey", RYDN_SECRET="yourSecret")
b2 <- find_place("Berlin, Germany")  
b2[c("latitude", "longitude")]
```

<kbd>**Bing**</kbd>:
[taRifx.geo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taRifx.geo/index.html) (works with Google) and supposedly works with Bing, but I could never get it to work, so I wrote my own function.

```r
bGeoCode <- function(str, BingMapsKey){
    require(RCurl)
    require(RJSONIO)
    u <- URLencode(paste0("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=", str, "&maxResults=1&key=", BingMapsKey))
    d <- getURL(u)
    j <- fromJSON(d,simplify = FALSE) 
    if (j$resourceSets[[1]]$estimatedTotal > 0) {
      lat <- j$resourceSets[[1]]$resources[[1]]$point$coordinates[[1]]
      lng <- j$resourceSets[[1]]$resources[[1]]$point$coordinates[[2]]
    }
    else {    
      lat <- lng <- NA
    }
    c(lat,lng)
}  

bGeoCode("Berlin, Germany", "yourAPIkey")
```

<kbd>**Google**</kbd>:

```r
library(ggmap)  
register_google(key = "yourAPIkey")
geocode("Berlin, Germany", source="google")
```

Comment: Important info on `ggmap` usage https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/readme/README.html